# editMode not working in case of .sheet or .fullScreenCover but with NavigationLink

Tags: list, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, editmode

I'm trying to enable editMode, i.e to come from here:

[image]

to here :

[image]

with the following code:

```
struct DetailSheet: View {

@State private var items: [Item] = (0..<5).map { Item(title: "Item #\($0)") }

var body: some View {
    NavigationView { // this line to be deleted for using navigationLink
    List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.title)
                }
                .onMove { (from, to) in
                    print("just a dummy")
                }
            } // List
                .navigationBarTitle("List")
              
              .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
   } // this line to be deleted for using navigationLink
}
```

}

This works fine, if it is the first view being called from scenedelegate. If I request it from a different "first" view with

```
 .sheet(isPresented: $showDetailSheet, content: {DetailSheet()})
```

or

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDetailSheet, content: {DetailSheet()})
```

It does not work anymore. It does work again, if I request the view with a NavigationLink ( if I delete the two lines for NavigationView{ and }.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, can anyone explain me, why editMode doesn't work, if the view was requested by .sheet?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is the code of the view (which is called from SceneDelegate) from where I call up DetailView

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@State var showDetailSheet : Bool = false


var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
    List {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailSheet(), label:{ Text("naviDetailSheet")})
        Button(action: {showDetailSheet = true}){Text("DetailSheet")}
        
       
     } // List
        
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    } // Navi
    .sheet(isPresented: $showDetailSheet, content: {DetailSheet()})
//        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDetailSheet, content: {DetailSheet()})
    
        }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by * If I request it from a different "first" view*? Could you give full reproducible code how did that? With Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1 the code in question works fine in sheet.

Comment: Thx for your response, I updated the question. I'm using Xcode 12.2, iOS 14.2. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it work fine. Looks like its 14.2 bug.

Comment: ah, ok, do you think that's why - mmh too bad. Wondering how I can continue now with my project...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can mess up `EditButton` (and more generally the `editMode` environment value) are extensions on `Binding`. Specifically, if you make `Binding` conform to `Equatable`, problems will occur with `editMode`.

Change any reference of:

```
extension Binding : Equatable where Value : Equatable {
```

to

```
extension Binding : Equatable where Value == MyType {
```

Where `MyType` is the name of your type (which obviously cannot be `EditMode`, otherwise the problem will persist).